# Should we have some interactive games or tools about statistics and data science? If yes, Suggest game or tool ideas

Tags: discussion, feature-request

In my opinion, such game should exist

1. To learn basics of statistics and improve basic concepts.
2. To improve site traffic.

We can add those games beside the chat window, or as a sidebar beside main site.

**Sample Game 1:**

There will be a Gaussian curve. The user requires to put standard deviations and means and the curve will shift accordingly.

**Sample Game 2:**

Student's T distribution where the user have to put different values for degree of freedom and to see when the curve approaches the Gaussian

**Sample game 3:**

> chi-square distribution  with k degrees of freedom is the distribution of a sum of the squares of k independent standard normal random variables (Wikipedia)

How different independent normal random variables make up the Chi square will be visualised.

**Sample game 4:**

Hypothesis testing: Type 1 error and type 2 error.
There will be a table.

> [image] ... From Wikipedia.

Computer will tell whether H0 is true or H1 is true. The user have to click "Accept null hypothesis" or "Reject null hypothesis". The computer will hilioght the box on whether the user took right decision or made an error.

**There is no hurry to implement the games**. Feel free to suggest such silly games to develop insight into statistics, and to learn very basics of statistics.

The ideas will help the

- Beginners or novices.
- Non-mathematics or Non-statistics people.
- Those having misconceptions and confusions.
- Those not getting the concepts and links.

Comment: This site already exists at http://www.rossmanchance.com/applets.html.

Comment: @whuber Oh thank you. It answers my another question on main site. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/477242/website-or-app-recommendation-for-visualising-statistics-concept-comparable-to This is great answer to that.

Answer (score 12):

We have no control on the code used on the site, so there is no way for us to introduce new features to the site. You could send this to Stack Exchange Inc as a feature request, but I find it unlikely that they would introduce site-specific features given how many Stack Exchange sites there are. Moreover, this is a Q&A site, it has a specific purpose.

Comment: I have seen different times in some other SE, feature requests for tools etc had been discussed such as this one https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3636/redesigning-biology-stack-exchange-extended.

Comment: @AlwaysConfused: How many have been implemented? It's a nice idea, & no harm in discussing it; but the chance of SE's implementing it is, in my opinion, negligible.

Comment: @Scortchi-ReinstateMonica is an optimist. I don't see this as happening ever.

Comment: Probabilities are never zero, even when something is impossible.